# MYSQL ORDER BY date of type Varchar

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to sort my resultset with respect to date which is of varchar type and in this format (dd/MMM/YYYY) but the problem is its not working fine.
I am using this query after a lot of search but still unable to get my desired result.

```
SELECT `batch_expiry` FROM `batchwise_stock` ORDER BY str_to_date(`batch_expiry`, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Sorting is Not doing properly but getting this sorted dates

```
29/Apr/2020
03/May/2020
16/May/2020
12/May/2020
14/May/2020
```

Please need help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Store dates as dates and move on

Comment: Why did you chose `varchar` for a column of "dates", that will make things like this question harder. Also it will be time consuming to process every record in the table with `str_to_date` function before it gets ordered.

Comment: If you stored your dates properly as actual dates instead of VARCHAR, you wouldn't have these sorts of issues. You can format them for display in your SELECT statement. You should find a good book or tutorial on databases and SQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that your dates are not in the format `%Y/%m/%d`.  In that format, the month is *numeric*.  Your format is `%Y/%b/%d`, so use that:

```
order by str_to_date(batch_expiry, '%d/%b/%Y')
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=639c1240b027547ad854579a9a2437d5) is a db<>fiddle.

The result of your expression is `NULL`, because the date column cannot be converted into that format.  All the `order by` keys are then equivalent, so the ordering in the result set is arbitrary.

As Strawberry points out in a comment, you should store your date values using the proper type, not as a string.